# android In-App Purchase API 3 consuming test purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using API 3 for in app feature in my app.Currently for test purpose i am using test item code

> android.test.purchased

Everything works fine i am able to buy product.But if i click "Purchase" button again, it says"already purchased" and need 30 minutes to let user buy again.Then i tried to consume this product using the following code but its ends up inside `QueryInventoryFinishedListener's` if(result.isFailure) condition.Following is my code for consuming

```
public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);

    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                Inventory inventory) {


            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure

                Log.i("Ajji", "Failed in Query Inventory Finished Listener");

            } else {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);

            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // clickButton.setEnabled(true);

                Log.i("Ajji", "Item Consumed Successfully");
                rowPayment.setClickable(true);

            } else {
                // handle error
                Log.i("Ajji", "Not Consumed");
            }
        }
    };
```

I call this method for consuming item, Further i am using  `Trivial Drive`sample project of google to make calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution thank you.I needed to edit the security.java file from Trivial drive Project .I changed "return false" line in the verifyPurchase  method to "return true" (dont forget its only for debug mode) .Now I can consume test in app successfully .Following is the edit of Verify Purchase method

```
public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey,
        String signedData, String signature) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey)
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
    return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
}
```